# Order table by number of matches

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have following database schema:

Applicants table:

```
applicant_id  | name 
--------------|----- 
      1       | Bill  
      2       | Tom  
      3       | Sam   
      4       | Alex
```

Skills table:

```
skill_id  | skill_name 
----------|-----------
    1     |    C++  
    2     |    java  
    3     |    html   
    4     |    PHP
```

ApplicantSkills (many-to-many between applicants and skills)

```
applicant_id  | skill_id 
--------------|-----------
      1       |     1  
      2       |     1  
      2       |     2   
      2       |     3  
      3       |     1  
      3       |     2
```

I want to select all applicants, but order them by number of matches with particular list of skills.

For example, if my list of skills is C++, java and html I want them to be ordered like this:

```
 name | matches
------|--------- 
 Tom  |    3   
 Sam  |    2 
 Bill |    1
 Alex |    0
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution proposed by **MM93** was *almost* correct. There was missing `GROUP BY` clause in inner query and `IFNULL` in main query.

In case someone is interesting here is correct solution:

```
SELECT a.applicant_name, IFNULL(sg.matches, 0)
FROM Applicants a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT a.applicant_id, count(s.skill_id) as matches
    FROM Applicants a
        JOIN ApplicantSkills aps ON aps.applicant_id = a.applicant_id
        JOIN Skills s ON aps.skill_id = s.skill_id
    WHERE s.skill_name IN ('C++','java','html')
        GROUP BY(a.applicant_id)
) sg ON a.applicant_id = sg.applicant_id
ORDER BY sg.matches DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

- `Left Outer Join` : To get all the `applicants` from `applicants` table even though he does not have any `skill`(*Alex*)
- `Count Aggregate` : To `Count` the skill of each `applicants`
- `Order by` : To order the result based on number of skills that applicants possess

Try this

```
SELECT          a.NAME , 
                Count(skill_id) AS matches 
FROM            applicants A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                (SELECT     applicant_id, 
                            s.skill_id 
                 FROM       applicantskills 
                 INNER JOIN skills s 
                 ON         a.skill_id = s.skill_id 
                 WHERE      skill_name IN ('C++','java','html')) ask 
ON a.applicant_id= ask.applicant_id 
ORDER BY   matches DESC
```

Comment: Sorry, but the query orders applicants just by number of possessed skills, not by number of matches with a list of skills.

Comment: @user3715778 - Check now, Updated my answer